# Autostart electron application at archlinux LXDE boot

Tags: electron, archlinux, autostart

I'm a little newbie in the arch linux world, but i am a bit lost in this.
I have developped an electron app, simply one html page and one js page.

This application is a launcher for a machine the aim of this application is :

When i start the system, I must not see the wallpaper but directly the electron application.

The machine runs on Archlinux with LXDE environment.

I have been searching for a long time now, trying editing the /etc/xdg/LXDE/... lxsession/autostart

It is working, but the application takes 30 seconds to start....

I have been trying to change and run locally the application using chromium in command line in kiosk mode, but even chromium starts in 30 seconds.

I have been trying to use firefox instead, but it is the same situation.

The machine is composed of 4 cores intel, i don't think it is material beacause the system if very fast when i want to launch an application manually...

Sorry for my bad english,

I will appreciate, every information in order to know, how to privilege electron app boot within 1 second on arch linux / lxde

Thanks for advance,

Tom.

Comment: As I know, LXDE starts its services first, and then launches all autostart apps when it's ready, so that there is no race condition if autostart apps require LXDE services. I think there is no option to priorise your autostart apps over LXDE services, but I may be wrong...

Comment: Thank for your quick answer, i have more information about the time and services on my system : with running the command : systemd-analyze which returns me

 :]# systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.829s (firmware) + 14.846s (loader) + 3.653s (kernel) + 52.487s (userspace) = 1min 16.817s
graphical.target reached after 52.487s in userspace

Comment: The graphical target is reached in the moment the X server has been started, LXDE and its services will be started once you log in. SystemD has nothing to do with LXDE autostart processes.